# How to accept user data from console

Tags: java, console-application, bufferedreader

My console java application generates a 3x3 matrix containing some random numbers.What i want to do is delete some random numbers from the set and instead allow the user to input those numbers

[image]

I have tried the following so far but its not working

```
   package magicsquare;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

public class MagicSquare {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter the size of the matrix : ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (n > 5 && n < 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 2 to 5 ");
        } else {
            int A[][] = new int[n][n]; // Creating the Magic Matrix
            int i, j, k, t;
            /*Initializing every cell of the matrix with 0 */
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    A[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            /* When the size of the matrix is Odd */
            if (n % 2 != 0) {
                i = 0;
                j = n / 2;
                k = 1;
                while (k <= n * n) {
                    A[i][j] = k++;
                    i--; // Making one step upward
                    j++; // Moving one step to the right 
                    if (i < 0 && j > n - 1) // Condition for the top-right corner element 
                    {
                        i = i + 2;
                        j--;
                    }
                    if (i < 0) // Wrapping around the row if it goes out of boundary 
                    {
                        i = n - 1;
                    }
                    if (j > n - 1) // Wrapping around the column if it goes out of boundary 
                    {
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    if (A[i][j] > 0) // Condition when the cell is already filled
                    {
                        i = i + 2;
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            } /* When the size of the matrix is even */ else {
                k = 1;
                /* Filling the matrix with natural numbers from 1 till n*n */
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        A[i][j] = k++;
                    }
                }
                j = n - 1;
                for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
                    /* swapping corner elements of primary diagonal */
                    t = A[i][i];
                    A[i][i] = A[j][j];
                    A[j][j] = t;
                    /* swapping corner elements of secondary diagonal */
                    t = A[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = A[j][i];
                    A[j][i] = t;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            /* Printing the Magic matrix */
            System.out.println("The Magic Matrix of size " + n + "x" + n + " is:");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    //remove random element from array
                   Random rand = new Random();   
                  for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
                  {
                  int randomNum1 = rand.nextInt((n-1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                  int randomNum2 = rand.nextInt((n-1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                  BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                  A[randomNum1][randomNum2] = Integer.parseInt(dr.readLine());
                  }
                    System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**

What i want to happen is that the matrix is displayed with some numbers missing.Then the user put his cursor at the missing spots and then input the numbers

Comment: @Thevenin added code

Comment: Please add the necessary code so that others can run it quickly – minimal _and_ complete: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hagello i added whole code

Comment: "it is not working". Please reduce the problem space by explaining what is actually happening versus what was desired.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you let the user choose several numbers for every number of the matrix displayed, so it needs several inputs before one number is printed. Do you want something like this?

```
                /* Printing the Magic matrix */
        System.out.println("The Magic Matrix of size " + n + "x" + n + " is:");
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //lets a user choose 2 numbers to be replaced
            System.out.println("Please input a number: ");
            int randomNum1 = rand.nextInt((n - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            int randomNum2 = rand.nextInt((n - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            A[randomNum1][randomNum2] = Integer.parseInt(dr.readLine());
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Edit: it may happen that the same number is replaced twice with this code.

Answer (score 3):

Went through the code and all seems well except for the way you print and "render" your matrix. Because you use loop of 5 rounds for random values inside the loop that goes through every value in the table, the random values are changed 5 times the size of the matrix. This in combination with the fact that the values the buffer reads stay in place after inputted makes the drawing of the array messy, leaving the inputted values as separate lines in your otherwise fine draw loop.

```
            // render 
    drawMatrix(); //draw orginal values
    changeValues(); // change the random values
    drawMatrix(); // draw again to show the new values

}
            public void drawMatrix(){
        /* Printing the Magic matrix */
            System.out.println("The Magic Matrix of size " + n + "x" + n + " is:");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                // print array current value
                System.out.print(A[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public void changeValues(){
        //remove random element from array (5 times here, 0 to 4)
             Random rand = new Random();   
             for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
             {
                int randomNum1 = rand.nextInt((n-1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                int randomNum2 = rand.nextInt((n-1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                BufferedReader dr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                A[randomNum1][randomNum2] = Integer.parseInt(dr.readLine());
             }
        }
```

Using something like this, you will be only changing the values once and drawing your new array afterwards. The orginal array is also drawn for comparison.

- Do note that if using the methods like I did, you will have to either pass on the required values to the functions and set your variables with the return values or increase their visibility to the scope of the whole class, the latter solution being messier yet less work intensive out of the two.

Another way of fixing the problem would be to caluclate the random matrix spaces you want to ask from the user before drawing at all. However this will also require you to ask the values from the user before drawing because otherwise it will leave the buffered reader input in midst of the matrix.

Because of the way input works in the command prompt, it seems like the best solution to never ask for values at the same time as drawing something and instead use some form of render loop where you ask for user input and do the drawing separately (still inside the render). For example, in a game you could have a loop that draws the map, then gets the user input and again draws the map accordingly to the input afterwards.

Comment: Check the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)  for instructions on how to implement mouse input events  . You're also going to need some form of function to match the click input coordinate with the ones in your array.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest: [Lanterna is a Java library allowing you to write easy semi-graphical user interfaces in a text-only environment](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) or may be some other similar library.

Answer (score -2):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int i = in.nextInt();
String s = in.next();
```

Now you can manipulate the output based on the inputs of int i and String s.